# CentOS: Outgoing traffic when main IP is null routed?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

My datacenter null routes IP addresses automatically when it sees that they are being attacked, and I'm all for that. However, today I noticed that when the main `eth0` IP address is null routed, all outgoing connections (i.e. `cURL`, [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents), etc) on the server go through that IP, meaning that any external services are essentially unreachable for me.

This is an issue because all of my websites are hosted on IP addresses separate from the main one, so that when the main IP was null routed, the others would remain up, as the other IP's are hidden by CloudFlare.

Is there anyway I can have outgoing traffic "bound" to a different IP than the main `eth0` IP address (or as WHM refers to it, the `Main/shared IP for: root`). It'd be even better it were possible to allow only a specific IP to have its outgoing traffic go through a different source.

With that being said, the server is running on `CentOS 5`, with `WHM` to run all the web related stuff.

Comment: I would reserve an IP for outgoing traffic (and maybe management) especially if you have to deal with DDoS attacks regularly.

Comment: Some commands have an option that lets you specify the interface to use, for example curl has `--interface <name>`

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about your configuration? How many servers? Load balancer? Network configuration of the server? Where is the gateway? How many public ip addresses do you have?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can instruct Linux kernel to use different IP for outgoing traffic.  This is achieved through using the iproute2 package.  There is 'src' argument to 'ip route' command which specifies what IP address to use for routing for the specific route.  Therefore, you can change the source IP address for your default route, e.g.:

```
ip route replace default via <your_gateway> src <your_alternate_IP_here> dev eth0
```